# Creating a service principal with the Azure java sdk fails

Tags: azure, azure-sdk

I am trying to create a service principal using the azure sdk. However, I am receiving an error

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

What am I doing wrong? I am doing the following:

1. Create a service principal with the Owner role

   ```
   az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "OrbitTest5" --role Owner --sdk-auth
   ```
2. Pass the credentials for the created service principal to a credential provider via environment variables

   ```
   public class AzureAppEnvCredentialProvider implements AzureCredentialProvider {
     public static final String ENV_CLIENT_ID = "CLIENT_ID";
     public static final String ENV_TENANT_ID = "TENANT_ID";
     public static final String ENV_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = "SUBSCRIPTION_ID";
     public static final String ENV_CLIENT_SECRET = "CLIENT_SECRET";

     private final String subscriptionId;

     public AzureAppEnvCredentialProvider() {
       this.subscriptionId = Preconditions.checkNotNull(System.getenv(ENV_SUBSCRIPTION_ID));
     }

     @Override
     public AzureTokenCredentials getCredentials() {
       final String clientId = Preconditions.checkNotNull(System.getenv(ENV_CLIENT_ID));
       final String tenantId = Preconditions.checkNotNull(System.getenv(ENV_TENANT_ID));
       final String clientSecret = Preconditions.checkNotNull(System.getenv(ENV_CLIENT_SECRET));
       return new ApplicationTokenCredentials(clientId, tenantId, clientSecret, AzureEnvironment.AZURE);
     }

     @Override
     public String getSubscriptionId() {
       return this.subscriptionId;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use the credentials to create a service principal with the java sdk

   ```
       azureAuthClient = Azure.configure().authenticate(credentialProvider.getCredentials());

       final ServicePrincipal servicePrincipal = 
           azureAuthClient.servicePrincipals()
           .define(clusterId)
           .withNewApplication("http://easycreate.azure.com/" + clusterId)
             .definePasswordCredential("sppass")
             .withPasswordValue("StrongPass!12")
             .attach()
           .create();
   ```
4. Then I get an exception. I know my credentials are valid because I am able to create a resource group with the sdk and view it from the Azure web console.

   com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.GraphErrorException: Status code 403, {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at com.microsoft.rest.ServiceResponseBuilder.build(ServiceResponseBuilder.java:122)
   at com.microsoft.azure.AzureResponseBuilder.build(AzureResponseBuilder.java:56)
   at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner.createDelegate(ApplicationsInner.java:194)
   at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner.access$000(ApplicationsInner.java:45)
   at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner$2.call(ApplicationsInner.java:181)
   at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner$2.call(ApplicationsInner.java:177)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.deliverResponse(CallArbiter.java:120)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.emitResponse(CallArbiter.java:102)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:46)
   at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
   at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
   at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: According to the error information, it indicates that you have no permisson to do that. I assume that credential is invaild to create the servicePrincipal. You mentioned that you could create the resource group. The resource  for creating resource group  is `https://management.azure.com` But for creating the servicePrincipal, the resource should be  `http://graph.windows.net`  or `https://graph.microsoft.com`. If possible, please share the code how to get the credential.

Comment: @TomSun Added the information for how I get the credentials to step 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned that if we want to create servicePrincipal then the resource should be `http://graph.windows.net` or `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

So we need to add the permisson to operate the Azure AD Graph API or Microsoft Graph API.

And don't forget **`Grant permission`**.

I test it with Azure Active Directory API. I works correctly on my side.

**Demo Code:**

```
ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(client,
               tenant,
                key,
                AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

Azure.Authenticated azureAuthClient = Azure.configure().authenticate(credentials);
String clusterId = "xxxxxxx";
ServicePrincipal servicePrincipal =
                azureAuthClient.servicePrincipals()
                        .define(clusterId)
                        .withNewApplication("http://easycreate.azure.com/" + clusterId)
                        .definePasswordCredential("sppass")
                        .withPasswordValue("StrongPass!12")
                        .attach()
                        .create();
```

[image]